# Fast way to detect rectangles, which intersect with the given rectangle

Tags: c#, system.drawing

The application I'm maintaining has custom drawing functionality, which draws some king of "objects" on an [`Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) surface. Object boundaries are described with [`Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Sometimes I need to detect objects, whose rectangles are intersecting with given rectangle.

If the number of objects is large enough, simple iteration like this:

```
var objectsToManage = _objects.Where(_ => rc.IntersectsWith(_.InscribeRect));
```

obviously, too slow (`_objects` here is `List<MyObjType>`, `IscribeRect` is object boundaries, and `rc` is a given rectangle).

I'm thinking about how to do this much faster. First idea is to "sort" objects by theirs rectangles and put them into sorted set... But I'm suspecting, that I'm re-inventing the wheel.

Is there any well-known approaches to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be done using [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). You can find a c# implementation here: [Virtualized WPF Canvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx) (the quadtree code is not strictly related to WPF), also lots of info here: [ZoomableApplication2: A Million Items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx) and another implementation here: [PriorityQuadTree](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2009/05/21/priorityquadtree.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these articles.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd - Even if the links disappear, the only mention of the 'quatree' term would be enough as an answer.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: actually, I'm asking about concept/link... Obviously, this isn't a question, that could be answered win a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #region FnLineMerginRectandLines
    public static bool LineIntersectsRect(Point p1, Point p2, Rectangle r)
    {
        return LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y)) ||
               (r.Contains(p1) && r.Contains(p2));
    }

    private static bool LineIntersectsLine(Point l1p1, Point l1p2, Point l2p1, Point l2p2)
    {
        float q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y);
        float d = (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y) - (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X);

        if (d == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        float r = q / d;

        q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y);
        float s = q / d;

        if (r < 0 || r > 1 || s < 0 || s > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    #endregion
public class Line
{
    private int Point1X;
    private int Point1Y;
    private int Point2X;
    private int Point2Y;
    public Point P1;
    public Point P2;

    public Line()
    {

    }
    public Line(int left, int top, int width, int height)
    {
        this.Point1X = Convert.ToInt32(left);
        this.Point1Y = Convert.ToInt32(top);
        this.Point2X = Convert.ToInt32(width);
        this.Point2Y = Convert.ToInt32(height);
        P1 = new Point(Point1X, Point1Y);
        P2 = new Point(Point2X, Point2Y);
    }
    public Line(string left, string top, string width, string height)
    {
        this.Point1X = Convert.ToInt32(left);
        this.Point1Y = Convert.ToInt32(top);
        this.Point2X = Convert.ToInt32(width);
        this.Point2Y = Convert.ToInt32(height);
        P1 = new Point(Point1X, Point1Y);
        P2 = new Point(Point2X, Point2Y);
    }   
    public Line(Point p1, Point P2)
    {
        this.P1 = p1;
        this.P2 = P2;
    }
}


public static List<Line>getfourborders(Rectangle RT)
    {
        Line topline = new Line(new Point(RT.Left,RT.Top),new Point(RT.Width+RT.Left,RT.Top));// Top Line
        Line leftline = new Line((new Point(RT.Left,RT.Top)),new Point(RT.Left,RT.Top+RT.Height));// left Line
        Line  rightline = new Line((new Point(RT.Left+RT.Width,RT.Top)),new Point(RT.Left + RT.Width,RT.Top+RT.Height));// Right Line
        Line bottomline = new Line((new Point(RT.Left,RT.Top+RT.Height)),new Point(RT.Left+RT.Width,RT.Top+RT.Height));//bottom line
        List<Line> borderlines = new List<Line>();
        borderlines.Add(leftline);
        borderlines.Add(topline);
        borderlines.Add(rightline);
        borderlines.Add(bottomline);
        return borderlines;
    }

 //YourObjectList() contains a rectangle type
        public class myobject
        {
            public myobject(object S, Rectangle RT)
            {
            this.Rt = RT;
            this.anyobjecttype= S;
            }
            public Rectangle Rt;
            public  object anyobjecttype ;
        }

        public List<myobject> CompareRectangles(List<myobject> Rect ,Rectangle GivenRectangle)
        {
            List<myobject> intersectingobjects = new List<myobject>();
            Rectangle CompareWith = new Rectangle();//"_objects.Where(_ => rc.IntersectsWith(_.InscribeRect));"

            foreach(myobject iterate in Rect)
            {
                List<Line> BorderLines = new List<Line>();
                BorderLines.AddRange(getfourborders(iterate.Rt));
                bool Intersects = BorderLines.Any(x=>LineIntersectsRect(x.P1,x.P2,CompareWith));
                if (Intersects)
                    intersectingobjects.Add(iterate);
            }
            return intersectingobjects;
        }
```

create another function to get all the border lines(get four points and create four lines from rectangle 1 ) and check if any of the line merges with another rectanglecompare using lineintersectsRect if any of that returns true then the rectangle 1 will intersect with your rectangle R, you can loop it to check rectangle 2 intersects with rectanglecompare and so on..
make sure that you don't pass divide by zero exception in line intersects with line

Comment: I didn't get your idea. Looks like it requires the iteration on objects collection anyway. Isn't it?

Comment: for a rectangle to intersect another rectangle any of the border line should intersect with the 2nd rectangle.. so i get my first rects borders and check if any of the line intersects with 2nd rectangle.....bool truefalse = borderlines.Any(x => LineIntersectsRect(x.P1, x.P2, CompareWith));

Comment: The question isn't about "how to detect, that two rectangles are intersecting". Imagine, that there are tens of thousands of objects. My current code need to test *every* object in list.

Comment: @balajidileepkumar - Please write in sentences, using punctuation and proper casing. Your answer might be right but I can't read it.

Comment: you can iterate all the objects and check for all the rectangles .... if your list is large enough.. it will certainly take time depending on you r object list.. you can write, this is oop approach... sorry if i am naive